# Para o Python, qual a diferença entre pip x conda x anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda

Estou aprendendo python e vi que sempre aparece tutoriais para as ferramentas:

- pip
- conda
- anaconda

E fiquei em dúvida qual a diferença prática entre eles?

Answer (score 1):

Pip é um package manager para a linguagem Python.

Conda é um package manager para várias linguagens.

Anaconda é um conjunto de módulos para data science com python.